# Why doesn't the position of the Lunar Node (Rahu and Ketu) overlap with that of Sun during a complete solar eclipse?

Tags: astrology, eclipse

This year's total solar eclipse took place on 3rd Jul 2019 at 00:52:57 Hydrabad time.

The position of Sun, Moon, and Rahu, are as follows :

1. Sun : 76:30:20
2. Moon : 76:34:13
3. Rahu : 83:29:11

My understanding is that solar eclipses occur when no Moon takes place on the points of lunar nodes. Here, in this case, the Sun and Moon perfectly overlap each other, but Rahu is off by a few degrees.

Why is that? Should not all three (Sun, Moon, Rahu/Ketu) be on the same degree for total eclipse to take place? Or is there some mistake in my understanding?

The same observation holds true in the upcoming solar eclipse of 26 Dec 2019.